# Styled Components Autocomplete isn't working

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, styled-components

im working with styled components in vscode and I can't seem to make the autocomplete from vscode-styled-components to work. It's really weird bacause yesterday it was working, I've had the same issue with the autocompletion in Vuejs styles. I've tried uninstalling vscode and uninstalling every extension I have but nothing changes. Has anyone had this same issue?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? which plugins did you install? versions o VSC?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.